# Can't find grub-mkrescue

Tags: grub, cygwin, mingw

Im following the os tutorial on osdev
but i can't find grub-mkrescue it was not included in mingw a quick search told me to get cygwin but it was not included in cygwin either
Thats why im asking here where can i get this

Comment: You try use grub-mkrescue under windows? It strange. What OS you use?

Comment: Windows with WSL

Comment: AFAIK (50%) As Your current bootloader not grub, grub-mkrescue won't get required information so it useless. What You try to achieve? Try precreated live or rescue boot images.

Comment: i got it sorted out i reset sources.list to default and tried installing grub-common again and it worked